# How to recreate specific animation

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, slick.js

I'm trying to make an image slideshow that has a transition effect like [seen here](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/501822/screenshots/3985479/comp_1.gif). I unfortunately only have this gif to go by and I have not been able to locate live web example. The slideshow should show 3 images at a time, then slide to the next 3, and so on. I started with using the slick slider to do most of the slideshow work for me (this is not a requirement). But I'm having difficulty recreating a transition that looks like the effect in the sample. I tried animating padding between the images but that causes the images to change size and causing the images to go off center. Using `box-sizing: border-box` did not help in this case. Any help on how to create this transition would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
        speed: 500
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slick-slide img{
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.slick-slide{
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slick-active{
  animation: slidetransition;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
@keyframes slidetransition {
  0% {
    padding: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    padding: 0px 25px;
  }
  100% {
    padding:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="group1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/dd0909&text=Slide_1">
    </div>
    <div class="group1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/dd6809&text=Slide_2">
    </div>
    <div class="group1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/fdff3b&text=Slide_3">
    </div>
    <div class="group2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/3bff3b&text=Slide_4">
    </div>
    <div class="group2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/5d87ff&text=Slide_5">
    </div>
    <div class="group2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/ab8df8&text=Slide_6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try `margin` instead of `padding`?

Comment: Try staggering when the animation starts for each image using the `animation-delay` style. To achieve the rubber-banding effect, try playing around with the `animation-timing-function` style.

Comment: Alternatively, it looks like it could be simpler to go with `transition` styles instead of an animation.

Answer (score 2):

If you can group your items in groups of 3, this solution can work for you.

I am setting different delays to achieve the effect of the items moving separately and the grouping again

```js
var page = 1;

window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(changePage, 4000);
}

function changePage() {
  var previous = document.querySelector(".previous");
  if (previous) {
    previous.classList.remove("previous");
  }

  var active = document.querySelector(".active");
  active.classList.remove("active");
  active.classList.add("previous");

  page++;
  if (page > 3) {
    page = 1;
  }
  var id = "page" + page;
  var newActive = document.getElementById(id);
  newActive.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.carousel {
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.elem {
  height: 98%;
  width: 33%;
  font-size: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateX(300%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.active .elem {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.previous .elem {
  transform: translateX(-300%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.elem:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: tomato;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.elem:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.elem:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.active .elem:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.active .elem:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.active .elem:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="page active" id="page1">
    <div class="elem">1</div>
    <div class="elem">1</div>
    <div class="elem">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page" id="page2">
    <div class="elem">2</div>
    <div class="elem">2</div>
    <div class="elem">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page" id="page3">
    <div class="elem">3</div>
    <div class="elem">3</div>
    <div class="elem">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here another snippet, working with nbuttons, and responsive

```js
var page = 1;
var numPages = 4;

function forward() {
    changePage(1);
}
function back() {
    changePage(-1);
}
function changePage (inc) {
    var ele = document.querySelector(".carousel");
    if (inc > 0) {
        ele.className = "carousel forward";
    } else {
        ele.className = "carousel back";
    }


    page += inc;
    if (page > numPages) {
        page = 1;
    }
    if (page < 1) {
        page = numPages;
    }
    var id = page - 3;
    if (id < 0) {
        id += numPages;
    }
    document.getElementById("page" + (id % numPages)).className = "page";
    id ++;
    document.getElementById("page" + (id % numPages)).className = "page left";
    id ++;
    document.getElementById("page" + id % numPages).className = "page active";
    id ++;
    document.getElementById("page" + id % numPages).className = "page right";
    id ++;
    document.getElementById("page" + id % numPages).className = "page";
}
```

```css
.carousel {
  height: 200px;
  width: 98%;
  border: solid 3px black;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.page {
  eft: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page:nth-child(2) {
  op: 100px;
}
.page:nth-child(3) {
  op: 200px;
}

.elem {
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  font-size: 100px;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateX(300%);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.active .elem {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}

.left .elem {
  transform: translateX(-300%);
}

.forward .left .elem {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}

.right .elem {
  transform: translateX(300%);
}

.back .right .elem {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}

.elem:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.elem:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.elem:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightblue;;
}

.back .right .elem:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.back .right .elem:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.back .right .elem:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.back .active .elem:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.back .active .elem:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.back .active .elem:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.forward .left .elem:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.forward .left .elem:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.forward .left .elem:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.forward .active .elem:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.forward .active .elem:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.forward .active .elem:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}


button {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel forward">
  <div class="page active" id="page0">
    <div class="elem">1</div>
    <div class="elem">1</div>
    <div class="elem">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page right" id="page1">
    <div class="elem">2</div>
    <div class="elem">2</div>
    <div class="elem">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page" id="page2">
    <div class="elem">3</div>
    <div class="elem">3</div>
    <div class="elem">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page left" id="page3">
    <div class="elem">4</div>
    <div class="elem">4</div>
    <div class="elem">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="back()">back</button>
<button onclick="forward()">forward</button>
```

Comment: awesome approach with those nth-childs on the toggling .active class :)

Comment: Very nice. I'm trying to modify this to work in both directions but i'm having trouble keeping the previous group always to the left. Also, do you know how to make this responsive instead of relying on a set width and height? Thanks! Here's what I have so far based on your code:  https://jsfiddle.net/t95rua3c/75/  Sorry for mixing plain JS with JQuery, i'm more familiar with jQuery at this point :)

Comment: I have added another snippet. It works both ways, and it's responsive. (Just a matter of making the container width a percentage)

Answer (score 1):

For performance, a simple transform:translate with pure CSS is much better. If you just need 2 groups of 3 images, the following will do

```js
/*just toggles the "toggle" class on the "slider" element 
/* when clicking the toggle button*/
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("slider").classList.toggle("toggle");
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
/*hides the 3 overflowing imgs, preventing scrollbars*/
  width:100%; overflow:hidden;
}

.slider{
/*classic inline-block whitespace hack*/
  font-size:0; 
/* so the 2 "groups" are side by side */
  width:200%;
/*sets the transition between groups with some delay*/
  transition: transform 1.2s;
}

.slider img{
/*sizes the imgs acording to the fixed quantity*/
  width:calc(100% / 6);
/*set the transition for the imgs separation*/
  transition: transform 1s;
/*sets the default value for transform*/
  transform:translateX(0);
}

/*when "toggle" is not active, last images move to the right*/
.slider img:nth-child(4){transform:translateX(40px);}
.slider img:nth-child(5){transform:translateX(80px);}
.slider img:nth-child(6){transform:translateX(120px);}

/*when active, the slide moves 50% left so the second group shows*/
.slider.toggle{transform:translateX(-50%)}
/*when active, first two images move displaces to the left*/
.slider.toggle img:nth-child(1){transform:translateX(-80px);}
.slider.toggle img:nth-child(2){transform:translateX(-40px);}
/*when active, last two images reset to regular position*/
.slider.toggle img:nth-child(4){transform:translateX(0);}
.slider.toggle img:nth-child(5){transform:translateX(0);}
.slider.toggle img:nth-child(6){transform:translateX(0);}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider" id="slider">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/dd0909&text=Slide_1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/dd6809&text=Slide_2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/fdff3b&text=Slide_3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/3bff3b&text=Slide_4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/5d87ff&text=Slide_5">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/292929/ab8df8&text=Slide_6">
    </div>
</div>
<button id="toggle">toggle slides</button>
```

Feel free to use javascript to automatically switch the groups, it's just a matter of toggling the "toggle" class list. 
I've used a button toggle just for testing purposes.

Comment: That is looking pretty good. +1 But I do plan on having at least 3 groups. I also like how slick makes it infinite. I've continued to work on my original and i'm much closer now, but it's still not quite right, I think the previous transition needs to grow out instead of in if that makes sense: https://jsfiddle.net/x6mmgdh1/47/